# Impossible to convert 'WXWidget' in 'GtkWidget *

Tags: gstreamer, wxwidgets, gtk3

Here is my code :

```
/// Get the Gtk2+ window ID of wxPanel pnlview for GStreamer output
GtkWidget* video_window = pnlView->GetHandle();

// Without this line, GStreamer will create its own new window for the video stream.        
gtk_widget_realize(video_window);

GdkWindow *videoareaXwindow = gtk_widget_get_window(video_window);

data.xid = GDK_WINDOW_XID(videoareaXwindow) // Get xid for setting overlay later
```

were `pnlView` is define as `wxPanel*    pnlView;`

But the consol give me this error : `Impossible to convert 'WXWidget' in 'GtkWidget *` at the line where I initialize `video_window`

Can someone has any idea how to fix it ?

I just want to add my gstreamer window in my wxWindow

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used gstreamer, but I do sometimes use libvlc which is probably very similar.  When using libvlc to render into a wxWindow, I need to wait until the wxWindow is fully created before I can set vlc to use it.  This is done by adding an event handler for the window creation event.

The process of declaring and binding the event handler looks like this:

```
class MainWindow : public wxFrame
{
    ...
    // Event handlers
    void OnRendererWinCreated(wxWindowCreateEvent& event);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(...)
{
   ...
#ifdef __WXGTK__
    // On GTK+, we have to wait until the window is actually created before we
    // can tell VLC to use it for output. So wait for the window create event.
    pnlView->Bind(wxEVT_CREATE, &MainWindow::OnRendererWinCreated, this);
#elif defined(__WXMSW__)
    m_player.setHwnd(pnlView->GetHandle());
#endif
    ...
}
```

For libvlc, my window creation event handler looks like this:

```
void MainWindow::OnRendererWinCreated(wxWindowCreateEvent& event)
{
#ifdef __WXGTK__
    m_player.setXwindow(
        gdk_x11_window_get_xid(gtk_widget_get_window(pnlView->GetHandle()))
        );

    pnlView->Unbind(wxEVT_CREATE,&MainWindow::OnRendererWinCreated,this);
#endif
}
```

Based on the code you posted, I think the body of an event handler that will work for you should look something like this:

```
void MainWindow::OnRendererWinCreated(wxWindowCreateEvent& event)
{
#ifdef __WXGTK__
    /// Get the Gtk2+ window ID of wxPanel pnlview for GStreamer output
    GtkWidget* video_window = pnlView->GetHandle();

    GdkWindow *videoareaXwindow = gtk_widget_get_window(video_window);

    data.xid = GDK_WINDOW_XID(videoareaXwindow) // Get xid for setting overlay later

    pnlView->Unbind(wxEVT_CREATE,&MainWindow::OnRendererWinCreated,this);
#endif
}
```

---

Edit:

Here's a simple example of using GStreamer to draw onto a wxWindow on GTK.  This shows how to use the `wxEVT_CREATE` to get the XID for a window and how to use GStreamer's bus sync handler callback to pass that XID to GStreamer at the correct time.

This is basically a mashup of the [2nd tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/concepts.html) and the code snippet from the [GstVideoOverlay](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/gstvideooverlay.html?gi-language=c) page adjusted for wxWidgets.  Since this is based on the 2nd tutorial, it just shows a test pattern.  The `source` variable can be changed to show other videos.

Obviously this assumes GTK is using X11.  Some adjustments would be needed if Wayland is used instead, but I don't have a running distro that uses Wayland to test on, so I don't know what changes are needed there.

```
#include "wx/wx.h"

#ifdef __WXGTK__
    #include <gdk/gdkx.h>
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
#endif

#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/videooverlay.h>

class MainWindow : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MainWindow(const wxString& title);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    // Event handlers
    void OnRendererWinCreated(wxWindowCreateEvent&);
    void OnPlay(wxCommandEvent&);
    void OnStop(wxCommandEvent&);

    // Helper function
    void LoadVideo();
    void PlayHelper();

    // wx controls
    wxWindow* m_renderWindow;
    wxButton* m_playButton;
    wxButton* m_stopButton;

    // GStreamer data
    GstElement* m_pipeline;
    guintptr m_xid;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    // Create the UI widgets.
    wxPanel* bg = new wxPanel(this,wxID_ANY);
    m_renderWindow = new wxWindow(bg,wxID_ANY);
    m_playButton = new wxButton(bg,wxID_ANY,"Play");
    m_stopButton = new wxButton(bg,wxID_ANY,"Stop");
    m_renderWindow->SetBackgroundColour(*wxBLACK);
    m_playButton->Enable(true);
    m_stopButton->Enable(false);

    // Layout the UI.
    wxBoxSizer* szr1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxBoxSizer* szr2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    szr2->Add(m_playButton, wxSizerFlags(0).Border(wxLEFT|wxRIGHT|wxBOTTOM));
    szr2->Add(m_stopButton, wxSizerFlags(0).Border(wxRIGHT|wxBOTTOM));

    szr1->Add(m_renderWindow, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxBOTTOM));
    szr1->Add(szr2, wxSizerFlags(0));
    bg->SetSizer(szr1);
    Layout();

    // Set up the event handlers.
#ifdef __WXGTK__
    m_renderWindow->Bind(wxEVT_CREATE, &MainWindow::OnRendererWinCreated, this);
    m_playButton->Enable(false);
#endif
    m_playButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainWindow::OnPlay, this);
    m_stopButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainWindow::OnStop, this);

    // Initialize GStreamer.
    m_xid = 0;
    m_pipeline = NULL;
    gst_init(NULL, NULL);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    if ( m_pipeline )
    {
        gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
        gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
    }
}

void MainWindow::OnRendererWinCreated(wxWindowCreateEvent&)
{
#ifdef __WXGTK__
    // This event is no longer needed.
    m_renderWindow->Unbind(wxEVT_CREATE,&MainWindow::OnRendererWinCreated,this);

    // Get the XID for this window.
    m_xid = GDK_WINDOW_XID(gtk_widget_get_window(m_renderWindow->GetHandle()));

    // We can now load and play the video, so enable the play button.
    m_playButton->Enable(true);
#endif
}

void MainWindow::OnPlay(wxCommandEvent&)
{
    if ( m_pipeline )
    {
        PlayHelper();
    }
    else
    {
        LoadVideo();
    }
}

void MainWindow::OnStop(wxCommandEvent&)
{
    if ( m_pipeline )
    {
        GstStateChangeReturn ret =
            gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);

        if ( ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE )
        {
            wxLogWarning("Unable to set the pipeline to the paused state.");
            gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
            m_pipeline = NULL;
            m_playButton->Enable(true);
            m_stopButton->Enable(false);
        }
        else
        {
            m_playButton->Enable(true);
            m_stopButton->Enable(false);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::LoadVideo()
{
    // Create the elements
    GstElement *source = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", "source");
#ifdef __WXGTK__
    GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make("xvimagesink", "sink");
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink), m_xid);
#elif defined __WXMSW__
    GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make("d3dvideosink", "sink");
    WXWidget hwnd = m_renderWindow->GetHandle();
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink),
                                        reinterpret_cast<guintptr>(hwnd));
#endif

    //Create the empty pipeline
    m_pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

    if ( !m_pipeline || !source || !sink )
    {
        wxLogError("Not all elements could be created.");
        return;
    }

    // Build the pipeline
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(m_pipeline), source, sink, NULL);
    if ( gst_element_link(source, sink) != TRUE )
    {
        wxLogWarning("Elements could not be linked.");
        gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
        m_pipeline = NULL;
        return;
    }

    // Modify the source's properties
    g_object_set(source, "pattern", 0, NULL);

    PlayHelper();
}

void MainWindow::PlayHelper()
{
    GstStateChangeReturn ret =
        gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    if ( ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE )
    {
        wxLogWarning("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.");
        gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
        m_pipeline = NULL;
        m_playButton->Enable(true);
        m_stopButton->Enable(false);
    }
    else
    {
        m_playButton->Enable(false);
        m_stopButton->Enable(true);
    }
}

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() override
    {
        MainWindow* mainWindow = new MainWindow("wxWidgets GStreamer demo");
        mainWindow->Show();
        return true;
    }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

On mint it looks like this:

[image]

On windows it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for having accept the answer to fast but I can compile my program and I succeed to display the stream of Gstreamer in another window. However, when I use your methode, the consol tell me that the stream is running but nothing append on my wxWindow (and gstreamer does'nt open another window for the stream :/ Do you have an idea?

Comment: Thank for your help. but I always encounter the same problem whatever I try. At the line where I use GetHandle() I have this issue : Impossible to convert 'WXWidget' in 'GtkWidget *

Comment: For information, I'm on windows. Is it possible to tu use GTK with x11 on it?

Comment: I've updated the answer 1 final time to show how to do this on windows.  On windows, you don't need to wait for the window to be created and do all the other stuff.  You just get the HWND with GetHandle() and then pass that to the `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle` function (after casting the HWND to guintptr).